# Find a closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{H_{n-1}^{(2)}}x^{2n}}{n^2{{2n}\choose{n}}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, harmonic-numbers

I would like to know if it is possible to find a closed form of the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{H_{n-1}^{(2)}}x^{2n}}{n^2{{2n}\choose{n}}}.$$

Here $H_{n}^{(2)}$ denotes the [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).

This series look similar to the $\arcsin(x)$ series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{n^2{{2n}\choose{n}}}$$
but I don't know how to combine it with harmonic number. I tried converting it to Beta function but that didn't seem to help much.

I am interested in an even more general question, i.e. finding the closed form of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{H_{n-1}^{(k)}}x^{2n}}{n^2{{2n}\choose{n}}}$$
for any positive integer $k$. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha or Mathematica gives $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k^2} }{n^2 \binom{2 n}{n}}\,x^{2 n}=\frac{2}{3} \arcsin^4 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Yeah,I want to know how did it come?

Comment: See [here](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#Potenzen_des_Arkussinus) for example, for a quick proof

Answer (score 3):

The result 
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k^2} }{n^2 \binom{2 n}{n}}\,x^{2 n}=\frac{2}{3} \arcsin^4 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
is obtained by entering a slightly modified latex code into Wolfram Alpha, for example [like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum%20_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%20%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csum%20_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%20n%7D%7D%7Bk%5E2%7D%7D%7Bn%5E2%20%5Cbinom%7B2%20n%7D%7Bn%7D%7D) (I don't know why this variant of Latex code works and other equivalent ones don't).

The only way I know of demonstrating this, is by already knowing the result and tediously evaluating the [Cauchy Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) for $\frac{1}{6}\left[2 \arcsin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]^2$, that is

$$\frac{2}{3} \arcsin^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{6} \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^{2 n}}{n^2 \binom{2 n}{n}}\right)^2=\frac{1}{6} \sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{x^{2 k}}{\left(j^2 \binom{2 j}{j}\right) \left((k-j)^2 \binom{2 (k-j)}{k-j}\right)}\right)$$

Perhaps someone else can devise a neater less tedious proof of this result.

Comment: Yeah i got this also,but don't know how to do next.

Comment: Follow the link that @nospoon gave you, and work your way through the proof given there, using the double differentiation technique, and perhaps correcting the odd typo along the way.